# what is the difference between these 2 MSBuild calls

Tags: xml, templates, tfs, build, msbuild

I'm a started in TFS, and I would like to customize my build sequence.
First of all, I'm trying to learn the default Template.
I can't figure out what is the difference between those 2 MSBuild calls.

```
<If Condition="[CleanWorkspace = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.CleanWorkspaceOption.Outputs]" DisplayName="If CleanWorkspace = CleanWorkspaceOption.Outputs" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
      <If.Then>
        <ForEach x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:PlatformConfiguration" DisplayName="For Each Configuration in BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations" Values="[BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
          <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:PlatformConfiguration">
            <ActivityAction.Argument>
              <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:PlatformConfiguration" Name="platformConfiguration" />
            </ActivityAction.Argument>
            <Sequence DisplayName="Clean Configuration">
              <If Condition="[BuildSettings.HasProjectsToBuild]" DisplayName="If BuildSettings.HasProjectsToBuild" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                <If.Then>
                  <ForEach x:TypeArguments="x:String" DisplayName="For Each Project in BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild" Values="[BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                      <ActivityAction.Argument>
                        <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="serverBuildProjectItem" />
                      </ActivityAction.Argument>
                      <Sequence DisplayName="Clean Project" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                        <Sequence.Variables>
                          <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="localBuildProjectItem" />
                        </Sequence.Variables>
                        <mtbwa:ConvertWorkspaceItem DisplayName="Convert Server Paths to Local Paths" Input="[serverBuildProjectItem]" Result="[localBuildProjectItem]" Workspace="[Workspace]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                        <If Condition="[System.IO.File.Exists(localBuildProjectItem)]" DisplayName="If File.Exists(Project)" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                          <If.Then>
                            <mtbwa:MSBuild CommandLineArguments="[String.Format(&quot;/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0}&quot;, MSBuildArguments)]" Configuration="[platformConfiguration.Configuration]" DisplayName="Run MSBuild for Project" GenerateVSPropsFile="[True]" MaxProcesses="[If (MSBuildMultiProc, 0, 1)]" OutDir="[BinariesDirectory]" Platform="[platformConfiguration.Platform]" Project="[localBuildProjectItem]" Targets="[New String() { &quot;Clean&quot; }]" TargetsNotLogged="[New String() {&quot;GetNativeManifest&quot;, &quot;GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems&quot;, &quot;GetTargetPath&quot;}]" ToolPlatform="[MSBuildPlatform]" Verbosity="[Verbosity]" />
                          </If.Then>
                        </If>
                      </Sequence>
                    </ActivityAction>
                  </ForEach>
                </If.Then>
              </If>
            </Sequence>
          </ActivityAction>
        </ForEach>
      </If.Then>
    </If>
    <mtbwa:SyncWorkspace DisplayName="Get Workspace" VersionOverride="[GetVersion]" Workspace="[Workspace]">
      <mtbwa:SyncWorkspace.RequestsFailed>
        <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="scg:ICollection(mtbc:IQueuedBuild)">
          <ActivityAction.Argument>
            <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="scg:ICollection(mtbc:IQueuedBuild)" Name="failedRequests" />
          </ActivityAction.Argument>
          <mtbwa:RetryRequests Behavior="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.RetryBehavior.DoNotBatch]" DisplayName="Mark Requests for Retry" Requests="[failedRequests]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
        </ActivityAction>
      </mtbwa:SyncWorkspace.RequestsFailed>
    </mtbwa:SyncWorkspace>
  </Sequence>
  <If Condition="[CreateLabel]" DisplayName="If CreateLabel" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
    <If.Then>
      <mtbwa:InvokeForReason DisplayName="Create and Set Label for non-Shelveset Builds" Reason="Manual, IndividualCI, BatchedCI, Schedule, ScheduleForced, UserCreated">
        <mtbwa:LabelWorkspace Comment="[&quot;Label Created by Team Build&quot;]" DisplayName="Create Label" Name="[LabelName]" Scope="[String.Format(&quot;$/{0}&quot;, BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.TeamProject)]" Workspace="[Workspace]" />
        <mtbwa:SetBuildProperties DisplayName="Set Label on BuildDetail" LabelName="[String.Format(&quot;{0}@$/{1}&quot;, LabelName, BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.TeamProject)]" PropertiesToSet="LabelName" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
      </mtbwa:InvokeForReason>
    </If.Then>
    <If.Else>
      <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage DisplayName="Write Message" Message="Not Labeling sources" Importance="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.High]" />
    </If.Else>
  </If>
  <TryCatch DisplayName="Try Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
    <TryCatch.Finally>
      <Sequence DisplayName="Revert Workspace and Copy Files to Drop Location" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
        <mtbwa:InvokeForReason DisplayName="Revert Workspace for Shelveset Builds" Reason="CheckInShelveset, ValidateShelveset">
          <mtbwa:RevertWorkspace DisplayName="Revert Workspace" Workspace="[Workspace]" />
        </mtbwa:InvokeForReason>
        <If  Condition="[Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropLocation)]" DisplayName="If DropLocation is Set" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
          <If.Then>
            <mtbwa:CopyDirectory DisplayName="Drop Files to Drop Location" Source="[BinariesDirectory]" Destination="[DropLocation]" />
          </If.Then>
        </If>
      </Sequence>
    </TryCatch.Finally>
    <TryCatch.Try>
      <Sequence mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="None">
        <Sequence.Variables>
          <Variable x:TypeArguments="s:Exception" Name="compilationException" />
          <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:IList(mtvc:Changeset)" Name="associatedChangesets" />
          <Variable x:TypeArguments="s:Boolean" Name="treatTestFailureAsBuildFailure" />
        </Sequence.Variables>
        <Parallel DisplayName="Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items">
          <TryCatch DisplayName="Try Compile and Test" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
            <TryCatch.Try>
              <Sequence DisplayName="Compile and Test">
                <ForEach x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:PlatformConfiguration" DisplayName="For Each Configuration in BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations" Values="[BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                  <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:PlatformConfiguration">
                    <ActivityAction.Argument>
                      <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="mtbwa:PlatformConfiguration" Name="platformConfiguration" />
                    </ActivityAction.Argument>
                    <Sequence DisplayName="Compile and Test for Configuration" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                      <Sequence.Variables>
                        <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="outputDirectory" />
                        <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="logFileDropLocation" />
                      </Sequence.Variables>
                      <Sequence DisplayName="Initialize Variables" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                        <Assign x:TypeArguments="x:String" DisplayName="Create OutputDirectory Per Platform and Configuration" To="[outputDirectory]" Value="[If (platformConfiguration.IsEmpty Or BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations.Count = 1, BinariesDirectory, If (platformConfiguration.IsPlatformEmptyOrAnyCpu, BinariesDirectory + &quot;\&quot; + platformConfiguration.Configuration, BinariesDirectory + &quot;\&quot; + platformConfiguration.Platform + &quot;\&quot; + platformConfiguration.Configuration))]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                        <If Condition="[Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropLocation)]" DisplayName="If DropLocation is Set" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                          <If.Then>
                            <Assign x:TypeArguments="x:String" DisplayName="Initialize LogFile Drop Location" To="[logFileDropLocation]" Value="[If (platformConfiguration.IsEmpty Or BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations.Count = 1, BuildDropProvider.CombinePaths(DropLocation, &quot;logs&quot;), If (platformConfiguration.IsPlatformEmptyOrAnyCpu, BuildDropProvider.CombinePaths(DropLocation, &quot;logs&quot;, platformConfiguration.Configuration), BuildDropProvider.CombinePaths(DropLocation, &quot;logs&quot;, platformConfiguration.Platform, platformConfiguration.Configuration)))]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                          </If.Then>
                        </If>
                      </Sequence>
                      <If Condition="[BuildSettings.HasProjectsToBuild]" DisplayName="If BuildSettings.HasProjectsToBuild" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                        <If.Then>
                          <ForEach x:TypeArguments="x:String" DisplayName="For Each Project in BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild" Values="[BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                            <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                              <ActivityAction.Argument>
                                <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="serverBuildProjectItem" />
                              </ActivityAction.Argument>
                              <TryCatch DisplayName="Try to Compile the Project" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                <TryCatch.Try>
                                  <Sequence DisplayName="Compile the Project" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                    <Sequence.Variables>
                                      <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="localProject" />
                                      <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="outputDirectoryPerProject" Default="[outputDirectory]" />
                                    </Sequence.Variables>
                                    <mtbwa:ConvertWorkspaceItem DisplayName="Convert Server Path to Local Path" Input="[serverBuildProjectItem]" Result="[localProject]" Workspace="[Workspace]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                                    <If Condition="[SolutionSpecificBuildOutputs]" DisplayName="If Build Outputs are Solution-Specific" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                      <If.Then>
                                        <Sequence DisplayName="Update Output Directory" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                          <Assign x:TypeArguments="x:String" DisplayName="Set Solution-Specific Output Directory" To="[outputDirectoryPerProject]" Value="[System.IO.Path.Combine(outputDirectory, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(localProject))]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                                          <If DisplayName="If Output Directory Exists" Condition="[System.IO.Directory.Exists(outputDirectoryPerProject)]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                            <If.Then>
                                              <mtbwa:WriteBuildWarning DisplayName="Write Duplicate Project Names Warning" Message="[String.Format(&quot;{0} conflicts with another solution/project. Build outputs for solutions/projects with the same name will be copied to the same directory. To separate the build outputs, change the name of one of the solutions/projects.&quot;, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(localProject))]" />
                                            </If.Then>
                                          </If>
                                        </Sequence>
                                      </If.Then>
                                    </If>
                                    <mtbwa:MSBuild CommandLineArguments="[String.Format(&quot;/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0}&quot;, MSBuildArguments)]" Configuration="[platformConfiguration.Configuration]" DisplayName="Run MSBuild for Project" GenerateVSPropsFile="[True]" LogFileDropLocation="[logFileDropLocation]" MaxProcesses="[If (MSBuildMultiProc, 0, 1)]" OutDir="[outputDirectoryPerProject]" Platform="[platformConfiguration.Platform]" Project="[localProject]" RunCodeAnalysis="[RunCodeAnalysis]" TargetsNotLogged="[New String() {&quot;GetNativeManifest&quot;, &quot;GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems&quot;, &quot;GetTargetPath&quot;}]" ToolPlatform="[MSBuildPlatform]" Verbosity="[Verbosity]" />
                                  </Sequence>
                                </TryCatch.Try>
                                <TryCatch.Catches>
                                  <Catch x:TypeArguments="s:Exception">
                                    <ActivityAction x:TypeArguments="s:Exception">
                                      <ActivityAction.Argument>
                                        <DelegateInArgument x:TypeArguments="s:Exception" Name="ex" />
                                      </ActivityAction.Argument>
                                      <Sequence DisplayName="Handle Exception">
                                        <Sequence.Variables>
                                          <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:ICollection(mtbc:IQueuedBuild)" Name="failedRequests" />
                                        </Sequence.Variables>
                                        <mtbwa:SetBuildProperties CompilationStatus="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Failed]" DisplayName="Set CompilationStatus to Failed" PropertiesToSet="CompilationStatus" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                                        <If Condition="[CreateWorkItem]" DisplayName="If CreateWorkItem" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
                                          <If.Then>
                                            <mtbwa:InvokeForReason DisplayName="Create Work Item for non-Shelveset Builds" Reason="Manual, IndividualCI, BatchedCI, Schedule, ScheduleForced, UserCreated">
                                              <mtbwa:OpenWorkItem AssignedTo="[BuildDetail.RequestedFor]" Comment="[&quot;This work item was created by TFS Build on a build failure.&quot;]" CustomFields="[New Dictionary(Of String, String) From { {&quot;System.Reason&quot;, &quot;Build Failure&quot;}, {&quot;Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps&quot;, &quot;Start the build using TFS Build&quot;}, {&quot;Priority&quot;, &quot;1&quot;}, {&quot;Severity&quot;, &quot;1 - Critical&quot;} }]" DisplayName="Create Work Item" Title="[String.Format(&quot;Build Failure in Build: {0}&quot;, BuildDetail.BuildNumber)]" Type="[&quot;Bug&quot;]" />
                                            </mtbwa:InvokeForReason>
                                          </If.Then>
                                        </If>
                                        <mtbwa:GetApprovedRequests DisplayName="Get Requests Approved for Check In" Result="[failedRequests]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="None" />
                                        <mtbwa:RetryRequests Behavior="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.RetryBehavior.DoNotBatch]" DisplayName="Mark Requests for Retry" Requests="[failedRequests]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                                        <Rethrow DisplayName="Rethrow the exception so the build will stop" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low" />
                                      </Sequence>
                                    </ActivityAction>
                                  </Catch>
                                </TryCatch.Catches>
                              </TryCatch>
                            </ActivityAction>
                          </ForEach>
                        </If.Then>
                      </If>
```

(This ofcource is a part of the XML)

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the output location of the binaries. The first one is when you set your build defitinion with `Output location  = SingleFolder` which calls MSBuild with `OutDir="[BinariesDirectory]"` which copies all binaries to the same directory.

The second one is when `Output location = PerProject` which copies each project binaries in their own subfolder.